# What't the relationship between SonarQube plugin and SonarQube rules?

Tags: sonarqube

I am new to SonarQube. I know there are a few plugins like **sonar-findbugs-plugin-2.1.jar** located in the directory \extensions\plugins. I am not very clear about the concept for the **plugins and rules**. What's the difference of them? I found an article saying ' **Writing custom rules in Java via a SonarQube plugin;**'. It seems that the rules are stored in the plugin, am I right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A SonarQube plugin is a extension of SonarQube that contributes new features to the platform. Those features can be of many kinds:

- Web widgets
- Computation of new metrics
- Authentication and authorization implementations
- SCM providers
- ... and for most plugins: Rules!

So to sum up, rules are brought to the platform thanks to plugins.